# Read security parameters in IE via javascript

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a web page which written in javascript. The browser which we supported is IE 10 or 11.

I am using ajax to post HTTPRequest to my server. The post datatype is JSON . So I need open "a security parameter in IE" to send JSON from the page to server. So I need to do this in my IE

> Internet Options -> Security -> Custom Level -> Miscallaneous ->
>   Access Data Sources Across Domains [Set Enable]

Actually all clients internet options are different. I want to make an alert when client's that property is Disable. So I need read that property at page load.

Is it possible reach IE security parameters read-only at client side?

Comment: No, it isn't possible.

Comment: I don't know IE at all, but you could always know if it is working by doing the request. If you've got an error, there is probably something wrong. And depending on the type of error it does raise, you could maybe know if it is because of this setting (there may even be some handy error message somwhere)

Comment: @Kaiido , it writes only "error" in detail text. I suppose that if another error occurs, it can return "error" (same text) for different case. So I can only alert sth like that "there is an error". But I want to categorize them.

Comment: convince me :) @Teemu

Comment: Internet Options are written into Registry, JS has no acces to it. You can always try, and when fail, inform the user to switch the CORS on.

Comment: If what you need to check is telling the difference between CORS error and an other network error, then the only frontend way would be using fetch method and its no-cors param. But I strongly doubt IE10 and 11 do support this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this case spesific.

```
// use XHR for understanding CORS status
var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
var xhrStatus = "Passive";

// if CORS is enabled in IE, at pageload the function below onload function calls,
xhr.onload = function () {
   var responseText = xhr.responseText;
   xhrStatus = "Active";
};

// if CORS is disable in IE, at pageload, it calls onerror function instead of onload
xhr.onerror = function () {
   xhrStatus = "Passive";
};
```